# Python length of roads inside polygons

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, linestring

I have two datasets: one about each road in a country (and its linestring), and another one about the polygons of each region. I want to estimate the length of each road in the polygon that is inserted.
I have over 500000 roads and 550 regions.

roads dataframe

```
id_route geometry
1        LINESTRING (432966.6 6715628.5, 432996.7 6715692.7, 433037.2 6715757.4, 433079.8 6715805.8, 433102.7 6715831.8)
2        LINESTRING (406567.2 6239938.1, 406634.3 6239863.4, 406647.3 6239845.5)
3        LINESTRING (406034.5 6239944.6, 406094.1 6239985.2, 406139.1 6240016.3, 406167.9 6240029.3, 406202.8 6240034.3, 406261.1 6240033.1, 406304.5 6240029.9, 406341.5 6240018.7, 406373 6239996.7, 406398.7 6239998, 406469.5 6239979.3, 406530.6 6239960.3, 406543.7 6239952.6, 406567.2 6239938.1)
```

region dataframe

```
id_region geometry
A         POLYGON ((-0.45495 44.95342, -0.40932 44.94761...
B         POLYGON ((5.80529 45.20620, 5.75468 45.19679, ...
C         POLYGON ((3.05875 50.78071, 3.08067 50.77286, ...
```

Here is my code:

```
import geopandas as gdp
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import shape

roads=gdp.read_file('roads.shp').to_crs('epsg:4326')
poly=gdp.read_file('region.shp')

intersect=roads.intersection(poly).length
```

But I obtain the following errors and a dataframe full of NaNs:

```
UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersection
  return lib.intersection(a, b, **kwargs)
UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'length' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.
```

I also tried the following code suggested here: [Length of intersections from a linestring and a grid shapefile by using Python GeoPandas & QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332167/length-of-intersections-from-a-linestring-and-a-grid-shapefile-by-using-python-g)):

```
sjoin = gdp.sjoin(roads, poly, how='inner', predicate='within')
roads.reset_index(inplace = True)
poly.reset_index(inplace = True)
poly['lines_within_geoms'] = poly['index'].apply(lambda x: sjoin[sjoin['index_right'] == x]['geometry'].tolist())
# But I do not understand where this factor_x comes from?
poly['lines_within_factors'] = poly['index'].apply(lambda x: sjoin[sjoin['index_right'] == x]['factor_x'].tolist())
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to reproject your region to the projection of your roads not the other way around

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but strangely I still obtain the first two errors. I converted the poly to ```epsg:2154```

Comment: For the regions this is the dataset: https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/6441661?sommaire=6436478 . For the routes this is the dataset: https://wxs.ign.fr/pfinqfa9win76fllnimpfmbi/telechargement/inspire/ROUTE500-France-2021$ROUTE500_3-0__SHP_LAMB93_FXX_2021-11-03/file/ROUTE500_3-0__SHP_LAMB93_FXX_2021-11-03.7z  file TRONCON_ROUTE.shp, but I am focusing on routes starting by D. This is a big folder. I edited the question and included the full coordinates for 3 routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproject both data frames to for example [EPSG:23032](https://epsg.io/23032), intersect and groupby region:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import geopandas as gpd

region = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Ny mapp\contours_circonscriptions_legislatives_03052022\circonscriptions_legislatives_030522.shp")
road = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Ny mapp\ROUTE500_3-0__SHP_LAMB93_FXX_2021-11-03\ROUTE500_3-0__SHP_LAMB93_FXX_2021-11-03\ROUTE500\1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2022-01-00175\R500_3-0_SHP_LAMB93_FXX-ED211\RESEAU_ROUTIER\TRONCON_ROUTE.shp")

region = region.to_crs("epsg:23032")
road = road.to_crs("epsg:23032")

intersected = gpd.overlay(df1=region, df2=road, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=False)
# intersected.geometry.isna().any()
# False

intersected["roadlength"] = intersected.geometry.length

#Calculate sum of road length per dep, in kilometers
result = intersected.groupby("dep")["roadlength"].sum().div(1000).round(0).astype(int).reset_index()
result = result.rename(columns={"roadlength":"roadlength_km"})

# result.head()
#   dep  roadlength_km
# 0  01           9713
# 1  02           8936
# 2  03          10317
# 3  04           3412
# 4  05           2577
```